# Use angular with strict Content-Security-Policy (CSP) - do not use unsafe-inline

Tags: angular, security

I try to create an Angular Single Page Application and would l like to use restrictive content security policies (for security reasons). The problem I face is, that I have to allow unsafe evaluation of inline styles:

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com blob:;
img-src 'self' data:;font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com;
connect-src 'self'; block-all-mixed-content
```

I seached the internet and stack overflow and could not find a way to get rid of this. I do not use webpack - thus I can not try the nonce approach. Is there a way to use nonce or any other way to avoid the use of unsafe-inline?

help is much appreciated.